# HTML5 Banner, using external Assets from own Webspace

Tags: html, banner, google-web-designer

i'm a small business owner and i create my own Ads for a long time now.
Right now i'd like to create an ad for my business witch contains a picture not easy to compress. And i have to be blow 100kb for inital Load.
I create my Ads in Google Web Designer, can i just replace the the HTML code like this?

From Local:

```
<gwd-image id="image_one" source="assets/image_one.png" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1751"></gwd-image>
```

to my Webhosting:

```
<gwd-image id="image_one" source="https://myweb.com/HTML5/image_one.png" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1751"></gwd-image>
```

It looks like everything works that way. All i know is that a single file shoud still be below 100kb and the connection needs to be https. I also created a robots.txt in that directory on my webspace.

Do i miss something?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

why is your image path, not the same on your webhosting since you are supposed to have the folder online?
it should remain:

```
source="assets/image_one.png"
```

Comment: thanks for your help: i'm not sure if i comprehend your question correctly. Only the assets are online right now, all other files including the are local. My Goal: Offloading the heavy images out of the .zip so i can stay below 100kb unzipped.